# How can I get the old (Win7,8) UAC dialog back in Windows 10 Anniversary Update?

Tags: uac, windows-10-v1607

In Windows 10 Anniversary Update Microsoft changed the [UAC prompt to a newer XMAL based dialog](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2016/04/22/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-14328-for-pc-and-mobile/):

[image]

> When you are prompted to enter your credentials or elevate a program,
>   you will notice the dialog now has a fresh and modern UI to align with
>   the design language in use across Windows 10

I don't like it and would get the old one back. Is this possible?

Comment: @RobertoTustana ask a new question if boot is still slow after optimizing boot with xbootmgr:  http://www.msfn.org/board/index.php?showtopic=140262

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Vishal Gupta found a way](http://www.askvg.com/tip-disable-modern-uac-prompt-and-credential-ui-in-windows-10/) to do it. Run regedit.exe, go to the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI\TestHooks` and change the value `XamlCredUIAvailable` from `1` to `0`.

[image: http://media.askvg.com/articles/images6/Disable_Modern_XAML_UAC_Prompt_Windows_10.png]

Now you get the old UAC dialog back.

Starting with Creator Update 1703, **[Build 14971](http://winaero.com/blog/microsoft-has-removed-the-classic-uac-prompt-from-windows-10/), this trick no longer works**. So you can only apply it on the Anniversary Update V1607, Build 14393.